# I can not update a text field that is in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to update a texfield which is located in Fragment, but it gives me error when running

from my MainActivity, I am sending a variable to a method

```
DescripcionFragment desc = new DescripcionFragment();
        desc.setTextdes(descripcion_local);
```

in DescripcionFragment I am getting and riding the texfield

```
public static DescripcionFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        DescripcionFragment fragmentsecond = new DescripcionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentsecond.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentsecond;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.v_tab_desc, container, false);




        return view;
    }


    public void setTextdes(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.descripcion_desc);
        view.setText(item);

}
```

error

```
06-25 19:05:30.008      976-976/tuchillan.directoriochillan E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-25 19:08:57.332      976-976/tuchillan.directoriochillan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tuchillan.directoriochillan/tuchillan.directoriochillan.FragmentLoca.Local_vista}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at tuchillan.directoriochillan.FragmentLoca.DescripcionFragment.setTextdes(DescripcionFragment.java:54)
            at tuchillan.directoriochillan.FragmentLoca.Local_vista.onCreate(Local_vista.java:121)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onCreateView` method is not called if you create the Fragment using the constructor, but is called by the system after the Fragment is added to the Activity. To set the TextView, use the `setArguments`method of the Fragment like you do in `newInstance`.

If you need to change the TextView later, after the Fragment is properly created, you can still use the `setTextdes` method.

Example:

```
public static DescripcionFragment newInstance(int page, String title, String description) {
    DescripcionFragment fragmentsecond = new DescripcionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    args.putString("desription", description);
    fragmentsecond.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentsecond;
}

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.v_tab_desc, container, false);

    TextView view = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_desc);
    view.setText(getArguments().getString("description"));

    return view;
}
```

For creating the Fragment, you need to call the static method, of course:

```
DescripcionFragment desc = DescripcionFragment.newInstance(page, "title", "description");
```

Comment: `DescripcionFragment desc = DescripcionFragment.newInstance(page, "title", "description");` . I add this before or AFTER you create the fragmentPageview `FragmentPagerAdapter.MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new FragmentPagerAdapter.MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

Comment: If you want to add the DescriptionFragment into the FragmentPagerAdapter, i'd suggest you to do it like here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html  and create the Fragment inside the `getItem` Method of the FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Sorry? I don't quite understand what you want to say with this. But the code is okay like that.

Comment: I explained the link code already had implemented in my project.

Comment: Is there still a problem with this?

Comment: `DescripcionFragment desc = DescripcionFragment.newInstance(page, "title", "description");` is being replaced with `DescripcionFragment.newInstance(1, "Descripcion",descripcion);` FragmentPageAdapter of class, and enters null

Comment: if the textfield returns a null

Comment: Where does it return null?

Comment: sorry, this returning me the value is in getItem `case 2: return DescripcionFragment.newInstance (page, "title", "description");` , is it necessary to create a second constructor?

Comment: Well, you have to create the `newInstance(int page, String title, String description)` method. If that's not the problem, then I don't understand you, sorry.

Comment: I paste my code. Textview me in delivering returns the value FragmentPage adapter and not delivering Local_vista, here my code http://pastebin.com/ZUxB1imG  "dess"